# python におけるCSVデータ読み込み時の文字コードエラー

Tags: python, flask

Python（Flask）におけるCSVファイルの読み込みで困っています。

Shift_JISで保存され、データがダブルクオテーションで囲まれているCSVデータがあります。
以下の２パターンでファイルを開き、中のCSVをカンマ分割して取得する部分でエラーになります。
ある行になると必ず下記エラーがでるのですが、その行のデータをみても、一見おかしいところはありません。
また、PythonのIDLEで同様に処理するとエラーが無いのですが、Flaskにて実行するとエラーになります。
もし原因がありそうでしたらよろしくお願いします。

（１）

```
fo=codecs.open(f,"rb",'shift_jis')
for line in fo:
    d=line.split(",")
```

エラー文
**UnicodeDecodeError: 'shift_jis' codec can't decode bytes in position 298-299: illegal multibyte sequence**

（２）

```
fo=open(f,"rb")
for line in fo:
    d=line.split(",")
```

エラー文
**ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.**

Comment: 当該部分のデータを提示するとよいかと思います。

Comment: 本当に "shift_jis" で保存されているのですか？いわゆる CP932 なのではないでしょうか。

position 298-299 とエラーにバイト位置が書いてあるので、そのバイト位置にある文字だけでも提示してくだされば、コードセットの問題かどうかの切り分けができます。

「一見おかしいところがありません」とありますが、質問者以外は「一見」することはできません。

Comment: 丁寧にご指摘いただいた上に、お返事が遅くなり、大変申し訳ありません。
ご指摘事項を順番に確認していき、ご報告させていただきます。
取り急ぎ御礼申し上げます。

Answer (score 1):

Excel 等の出力ファイルでしたら改行コードが違う可能性があるので、

```py
fo = open(f, 'rU')
for line in fo:
    d = line.decode('utf-8').split(',')
```

を試してみてはいかがでしょうか。
オプション`rU`はユニバーサル改行のテキストモードで読み込む（そのファイルが用いている改行コードで読み込む）ことができます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの内容も試してみます。
よろしくお願いします。